# Installing consoleexport extension into Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firebug

How do you go about installing the Firebug extension Consoleexport to Chrome?
I have downloaded an XPI file which seems to be for Firefox only?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Correct. [XPI files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPInstall) are just for Firefox. Therefore and because their code is bound to Firefox internal APIs you can't install Firebug or any of its extensions within Chrome.

Sebastian

Comment: Thank you for confirming but I do run Firebug with Chrome. I want to add the consoleexport extension to it.

Comment: Then you are not running Firebug but its "little brother" [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). Though ConsoleExport is a Firefox extension and can't be installed in Chrome.